# How to use Onclick/Ontouch to call either of two methods in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have two methods with description of two pictures, and on touching the picture/screen I want to alternate between the two on the screen. How can one do this using boolean?

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

/**
 * DrawView.java 
 * A first drawing view example
 */
public class DrawView extends View implements OnTouchListener
{

    private Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint backgroundPaintn = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_grass = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_grassn = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_door = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_doorn = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_house = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_housen = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_roof = new Paint();
    private Paint drawPaint_roofn = new Paint();
    private Paint circlePaint = new Paint();
    private Paint circlePaintn = new Paint();
    private Paint circlePaint_sun = new Paint();
    private Paint circlePaint_sunn = new Paint();
    private Paint textPaint = new Paint();
    private Paint textPaintn = new Paint();
    private Paint path = new Paint();
    private Paint pathn = new Paint();
    private Path trianglePath;
    private float sx, sy;

    public DrawView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);         

        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

        backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.rgb(0,250,205));
        backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        backgroundPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        backgroundPaintn.setColor(Color.rgb(107,92,240));
        backgroundPaintn.setAntiAlias(true);
        backgroundPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_grass.setColor(Color.rgb(124,252,0));
        drawPaint_grass.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_grassn.setColor(Color.rgb(63,104,73));
        drawPaint_grassn.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_door.setColor(Color.rgb(233,82,65));
        drawPaint_door.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_doorn.setColor(Color.rgb(105, 15, 5));
        drawPaint_doorn.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_house.setColor(Color.rgb(205, 133, 63));
        drawPaint_house.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_housen.setColor(Color.rgb(175, 142, 138));
        drawPaint_housen.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_roof.setColor(Color.rgb(160, 82, 45));
        drawPaint_roof.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        drawPaint_roofn.setColor(Color.rgb(67,52,51));
        drawPaint_roofn.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        circlePaint_sun.setColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 0));
        circlePaint_sun.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        circlePaint_sunn.setColor(Color.rgb(249, 245, 245));
        circlePaint_sunn.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        trianglePath = new Path();
        trianglePath.moveTo(70, 300); // starting point
        trianglePath.lineTo(170,250); // 1st vertix
        trianglePath.lineTo(270, 300); // 2nd vertix
        trianglePath.lineTo(70, 300); // 3rd vertix and close

        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        textPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        textPaintn.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        textPaintn.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        circlePaint.setColor(Color.rgb(211, 211, 211));
        circlePaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);

        this.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {

        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        // Draw white background
        canvas.drawRect(this.getLeft(), this.getTop(), this.getRight(), this.getBottom(), backgroundPaint);

        //draw a rectangle with blue paint
        canvas.drawRect(0,400, 540,600, drawPaint_grass); 
        canvas.drawRect(100,400, 240,300, drawPaint_house);
        canvas.drawRect(150,400, 190,335, drawPaint_door); 
        canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, drawPaint_roof); // or whatever paint you want


        //draw text with green paint
        canvas.drawText("Muhibur Rahim", 232, 565, textPaint);

        //draw a circle with red paint with the touch coordinates
        canvas.drawCircle(sx-30,sy-30, 3, circlePaint);

        //draw a circle with red paint with the touch coordinates
        canvas.drawCircle(80, 80, 30, circlePaint_sun);
    }

    public void onDrawn(Canvas canvas)
    {

        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        //canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        // Draw white background
        canvas.drawRect(this.getLeft(), this.getTop(), this.getRight(), this.getBottom(), backgroundPaintn);

        //draw a rectangle with blue paint
        canvas.drawRect(0,400, 540,600, drawPaint_grassn); 
        canvas.drawRect(100,400, 240,300, drawPaint_housen);
        canvas.drawRect(150,400, 190,335, drawPaint_doorn); 
        canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, drawPaint_roofn); // or whatever paint you want


        //draw text with green paint
        canvas.drawText("Muhibur Rahim", 232, 565, textPaintn);

        //draw a circle with red paint with the touch coordinates
        canvas.drawCircle(sx-30,sy-30, 3, circlePaintn);

        //draw a circle with red paint with the touch coordinates
        canvas.drawCircle(80, 80, 30, circlePaint_sunn);
    }


    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {   
        //update the coordinates for the OnDraw method above, with wherever we touch
        sx = event.getX();
        sy = event.getY();

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

My problem is with the last part of the code, public boolean onTouch...

Comment: I *think* I have answered your question below, but it is difficult to tell as your question is very skimpy on the details.

Comment: +1 bud, im a positive type of person

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean bool = false;
public int count = 0; // say before the constructor.

//then in your onDraw method take everything and encapsulate it in an if statement:

if(!bool){

//the code in your onDraw() method

}else{//here you would put the call to the other draw method like
onDrawn(canvas);
}
```

then in your overridden onTouch() method make like this

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{   
    //update the coordinates for the OnDraw method above, with wherever we touch
    sx = event.getX();
    sy = event.getY();
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
     if(count == 0){
     bool = true;
     count++;}
     if(count == 1){
     bool = false;
     count--;}
     }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

how about this?

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    if(!bool){
        // Draw white background
        canvas.drawRect(this.getLeft(), this.getTop(), this.getRight(), this.getBottom(), backgroundPaint);

        //draw a rectangle with blue paint
        canvas.drawRect(0,400, 540,600, drawPaint_grass); 
        canvas.drawRect(100,400, 240,300, drawPaint_house);
        canvas.drawRect(150,400, 190,335, drawPaint_door); 
        canvas.drawPath(trianglePath, drawPaint_roof); // or whatever paint you want

        //draw text with green paint
        canvas.drawText("Muhibur Rahim", 232, 565, textPaint);

        //draw a circle with red paint with the touch coordinates
        canvas.drawCircle(sx-30,sy-30, 3, circlePaint);

        //draw a circle with red paint with the touch coordinates
        canvas.drawCircle(80, 80, 30, circlePaint_sun);
    } else {
        onDrawn(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate on where to put my methods in? my method names are onDraw and onDrawn...

Comment: Doesn't work, am i supposed to include the method code including the declaration in the if else function?

Comment: give me one second i have my code altered for that ill give you the raw code

Comment: if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) sorry about that

Comment: my bad again i didnt notice i put a } instead of a ) in that if

Comment: Sorry, but I think this question made me lose my ability to post new questions here, is there anything I can do to return that? I didn't know commenting was such a crime :(

Comment: same thing happened to me before, you have to go around and answer some questions, and get reputation somehow, read the page with the question that it refers you to, you have to do alot more research before you ask a question, save questions as like a last resort

Comment: you can get back on, you just gota get your reputation up

Answer (score 1):

```
if (flag) {
  // call first method
  flag = false;
} else {
  // call second method
  flag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random randomizer = new Random();
if(randomizer.nextBoolean()==True){
}
else{
}
```